# HTML window inside window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been searching around the web for a very long time on how to get a window inside a window, not just a popup window.

For example, clicking "RyanM" on this page:
[image]

does this:
[image]

But how do you do it, and is it possible to do with only HTML and CSS?

Comment: The name is modal window or lightbox

Comment: Well, those are not technically windows, they just look and work like modal windows. Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Modal window in pure HTML and CSS**

You can achieve what you want doing this :

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GG9Sa/281/)**

Answer (score 0):

Its called a Modal Dialogue in UI terminology and it is made from normal HTML elements such as a DIV etc. You can achieve the same effect using a hover Pseudo class using CSS only. But you would need to use JavaScript to launch it onClick.

However, jQuery UI comes with Modal functionality built in:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

## jQuery UI

```js
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

## CSS hover

```css
#dialog {  
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dialogueContainer:hover #dialog {  
  display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="dialogueContainer">
  

<button>Show Dialogue</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog win
    dow can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsssqeaw/)

```js
$('#a').click(function(){
    $('.h').toggle()
});
```

```css
.h{
    display:none;
     position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:orange;
    box-shadow:0px 0 5px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.h img{
   
    margin:5px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">click</div>
<div class="h">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301"/>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
</div>
```